# Updating contents of Endpoints class using endpoints-proto-datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, endpoints-proto-datastore

i have a class which inherits from EndpointsModel

```
class User( EndpointsModel ):
  name = ndb.StructuredProperty( Name, required=True )
  dateOfBirth = ndb.DateProperty(required=True)
  userName = ndb.StringProperty( required=True )
  emailId = ndb.StringProperty( required=True )
```

Now, suppose i want to update the name for some user with some username. Since, the methods for User expects a User object as input and output, do i have to create a separate message class for name and then use it to update name like i would do if i was not using endpoints-proto-datastore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `request_fields` in your API method to limit the "request message" to a subset of the fields in `User`

```
@User.method(path='/user/{id}',
             http_method='PUT',
             name='update',
             request_fields=('id', 'name'))
def update_user(self, user):
    ...
```

Comment: What should i do if i want to pass the key for some User also ?